# How to fix this concatenation of two xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, concatenation

I want to concat two xml file.
**Here is the input1.xml:**

```
<schema>
    <sequence> 
        <section id="xxx">
            <nodeA id="a">
                <fruit id="small">
                    <orange id="x" method="create">                    
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Orange</color>
                            <year>2000</year>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>                           
                </fruit>
            </nodeA>
            <nodeB id="b">
                <dog id="large">
                    <doberman id="x" method="create">
                        <condition>
                            <color>Black</color>
                        </condition>
                    </doberman>
                </dog>
            </nodeB>
        </section>
    </sequence>
</schema>
```

**and here input2.xml**

```
<schema>
    <sequence>
        <section id="xxx">
            <nodeA id="a">                
                <fruit id="small">                    
                    <melon id="x" method="create">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Green</color>                            
                        </attributes>
                    </melon>
                </fruit>
                <lemon id="z" method="delete" />
            </nodeA>
            <nodeA id="b">
                <fruit id="small">
                    <lime id="x" method="create">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Yellow</color>
                            <year>2001</year>
                        </attributes>
                    </lime>
                </fruit>
            </nodeA>
            <nodeB id="b">
                <dog id="small">
                    <poodle id="x" method="create">                    
                        <condition>
                            <color>White</color>
                        </condition>
                    </poodle>  
                </dog>                
            </nodeB>
            <nodeB id="c">
                <dog id="small">
                    <terrier id="x" method="delete" />
                </dog>
            </nodeB>
        </section>
    </sequence>
</schema>
```

My output:

```
<schema>
    <sequence>
        <section id="xxx">
            <nodeA id="a">
                <fruit id="small">
                    <orange id="x" method="create">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Orange</color>
                            <year>2000</year>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>
                </fruit>
                <fruit id="small">
                    <melon id="x" method="create">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Green</color>
                        </attributes>
                    </melon>
                </fruit>
                <lemon id="z" method="delete"/>
            </nodeA>
            <nodeB id="b">
                <dog id="large">
                    <doberman id="x" method="create">
                        <condition>
                            <color>Black</color>
                        </condition>
                    </doberman>
                </dog>
                <dog id="small">
                    <poodle id="x" method="create">
                        <condition>
                            <color>White</color>
                        </condition>
                    </poodle>
                </dog>
            </nodeB>
        </section>
    </sequence>
</schema>
```

**While the expected output is:**

```
<schema>
    <sequence>
        <section id="xxx">
            <nodeA id="a">
                <fruit id="small">
                    <orange id="x" method="create">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Orange</color>
                            <year>2000</year>
                        </attributes>
                    </orange>
                </fruit>
                <fruit id="small">
                    <melon id="x" method="create">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Green</color>
                        </attributes>
                    </melon>
                </fruit>
                <lemon id="z" method="delete"/>
            </nodeA>
            <nodeB id="b">
                <dog id="large">
                    <doberman id="x" method="create">
                        <condition>
                            <color>Black</color>
                        </condition>
                    </doberman>
                </dog>
                <dog id="small">
                    <poodle id="x" method="create">
                        <condition>
                            <color>White</color>
                        </condition>
                    </poodle>
                </dog>
            </nodeB>
            <nodeA id="b">   <!-- I'm missing this node -->
                <fruit id="small">
                    <lime id="x" method="create">
                        <attributes>
                            <color>Yellow</color>
                            <year>2001</year>
                        </attributes>
                    </lime>
                </fruit>
            </nodeA>
            <nodeB id="c">    <!-- I'm missing this node -->
                <dog id="small">
                    <terrier id="x" method="delete" />
                </dog>
            </nodeB>
        </section>
    </sequence>
</schema>
```

The XSLT file is like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://a.com">
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <xsl:param name="input2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="to-merge" select="document($input2)" />

   <xsl:function name="a:id">
      <xsl:param name="ctx"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($ctx/local-name(), $ctx/@id)"/>
   </xsl:function>   

   <xsl:key name="match" match="/schema/sequence/section/*" use="a:id(.)"/>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[count(. | key('match', a:id(.))) = count(key('match', a:id(.)))]">
    <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

           <xsl:variable name="id" select="a:id(.)"/>
           <xsl:for-each select="$to-merge">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('match', $id)/*"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How to modify the xslt file to produce the required output? The key here is to keep the order of the node. If node exist from file1, we combine it, and if it isn't we put it at the bottom according to the order how they appear.

Thanks very much.

John

Comment: The XML you use in your question is both meaningless and based on wrong design. I will always ignore questions with such XML. In particular, it is too long, the attributes aren't meaningful, the names of the specific elements are arbitrary and not repeating, there are more than one element with the same `id`. This makes it very difficult to deduce common structure and/or relationships. I hope that you will improve the examples of future questions so that they would no longer be meaningless, unstructured, violating basic principles and confusing.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I apologize for it. It wasn't my intention to give confusing example it's just that it was the real xml structure that I'm working with (with the duplicate id and stuff). But I will try to give more meaningful example in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already use XSLT 2.0 I wouldn't bother with keys but instead use `xsl:for-each-group` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="url2" select="'test2012051302.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document($url2)"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sequence">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="section | $doc2/schema/sequence/section" group-by="@id">
      <section id="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*" group-by="concat(local-name(), '|', @id)">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, *, (current-group() except .)/*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </section>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use Saxon 9.4 HE to apply above stylesheet to your input samples I get the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema>
   <sequence>
      <section id="xxx">
         <nodeA id="a">
            <fruit id="small">
               <orange id="x" method="create">
                  <attributes>
                     <color>Orange</color>
                     <year>2000</year>
                  </attributes>
               </orange>
            </fruit>
            <fruit id="small">
               <melon id="x" method="create">
                  <attributes>
                     <color>Green</color>
                  </attributes>
               </melon>
            </fruit>
            <lemon id="z" method="delete"/>
         </nodeA>
         <nodeB id="b">
            <dog id="large">
               <doberman id="x" method="create">
                  <condition>
                     <color>Black</color>
                  </condition>
               </doberman>
            </dog>
            <dog id="small">
               <poodle id="x" method="create">
                  <condition>
                     <color>White</color>
                  </condition>
               </poodle>
            </dog>
         </nodeB>
         <nodeA id="b">
            <fruit id="small">
               <lime id="x" method="create">
                  <attributes>
                     <color>Yellow</color>
                     <year>2001</year>
                  </attributes>
               </lime>
            </fruit>
         </nodeA>
         <nodeB id="c">
            <dog id="small">
               <terrier id="x" method="delete"/>
            </dog>
         </nodeB>
      </section>
   </sequence>
</schema>
```

which I think is what you want.

Comment: Thank you it works beautifully! For the `<section id="{current-grouping-key()}">` what if there is more attributes and not just id, how I print them out?

Comment: Instead of `<section id="{current-grouping-key()}">...</section>` you could try `<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>...</xsl:copy>` or `<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>...</xsl:copy>`, depending on your needs (e.g. the first suggestion allows you to transform the attributes if needed with additional templates, the second suggestion simply copies the attributes).